# getting wrong results from a loop calculation and invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I have the below arrays and I need to calculate req[i] and JJ[i]. I'm getting allow the values zeros expect req[2] and req[8] but with wrong values. why that's happening?
the second issue is with the second line of JJ calculation (   JJ[i]= 0.00633*(2*np.pi*math.sqrt(kz[i]*ky[i])*dx[i])/(pvt['muo']*(np.log(req/well['rw']) + PP['s_h']))), it says invalid syntax. what wrong there?

these are the arrays I'm using:

and this is the code:

```
import numpy as np
#%% Importing modules Loading .yml/.yaml file
import yaml
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math  
import scipy.special as sc
import pandas as pd
  
# Productivity index:
# i=len(n) 
# req=np.zeros((n))
# JJ=np.zeros((n))
def Prod_index(res, pvt,num,well, PP, w, well_drc,i):
   for i in range(n): 
        if well_drc== 'v':
            req[i]= 0.28*math.sqrt(math.sqrt(ky[i]/kx[i])*dx[i]**2 + math.sqrt(kx[i]/ky[i])*dy[i]**2)/((ky[i]/kx[i])**0.25 + (kx[i]/ky[i])**0.25)
            JJ[i]= 0.00633*(2*np.pi*math.sqrt(kx[i]*kz[i])*res['h'])/(pvt['muo']*(np.log(req[i]/well['rw']))+ PP['s_v'])                 
        elif well_drc=='h' :
            req[i]=0.28*math.sqrt(math.sqrt(kx[i]*ky[i])*dz[i]**2 + math.sqrt(kz[i]/ky[i]*dy[i]**2)/((ky[i]/kz[i])**0.25 + (kz[i]/ky[i])**0.25)
            JJ[i]= 0.00633*(2*np.pi*math.sqrt(kz[i]*ky[i])*dx[i])/(pvt['muo']*(np.log(req/well['rw']) + PP['s_h']))
        return req, JJ
```

Comment: I couldn't add then with the code, so I posted them here. these are the arrays:                                                                                                                
    dx: [750, 1000, 1250, 750, 1000, 1250, 750, 1000, 1250]  #[ft]
    dy: [750, 750, 750, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1250, 1250, 1250]   #[ft]
    dz: 20 #[ft]

Comment: kx: [50, 25,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]  # permeability in x direction
    ky: [25, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 100, 150]   # permeability in y direction
    kz: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]  # permeability in z direction

Comment: it says invalid syntax because you miss closing paranthesis in right above line.